# transfer IDs for a booking

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a booking system in ruby on rails, I want a student to book an instructor. I have used devise and created separate models, instructor and student. When a student is logged in, they are able to pick their instructor which is listed, and press 'Book a lesson' both their IDs are transferred to the lesson new form.

I am having two problems, the button to transfer the chosen instructors ID and the student who is signed in ID, to the lessons new page, for the student to book a lesson time and date.

**Instructor#index**

```
<% @instructors.each do |instructor| %>            
   <%=instructor.id%> : <%= instructor.email %>
    <%#= button_to 'Book a lesson',   new_lesson_path(instructor_id: instructor) %>
    <%= link_to 'Book a Lesson',   {controller: :lesson, :action => :new, :instructor_id => @instructor.id} %>
        <% end %>
```

**Lessons Controller**

```
# GET /lessons/new
def new
    # @lesson = Lesson.new
    @instructor = Instructor.find(params[:instructor_id])
    @lesson = Lesson.new(student_id: Student.find(session[:student_id]).id)
   @lesson.instructor_id = @instructor.id
end
```

**lesson FORM new**

```
<%= form_for(@lesson) do |f| %>
<div class="main-title"> New Lesson for "<%= @lesson.instructor.email %> "</div>
 <%= f.hidden_field :instructor_id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :student_id %>

  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :lesson_date %><br>
<%= f.date_select :lesson_date %>
</div>
   <div class="field">
<%= f.label :lesson_start_time %><br>
<%= f.time_select :lesson_start_time %>
</div>
  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :lesson_end_time %><br>
<%= f.time_select :lesson_end_time %>
</div>
  <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Add a lesson" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IELBI.jpg)

Comment: What problems exactly are you having? Also you can chain active record methods like this:  `@lesson = Student.find(id: student_id).lessons.create(params)` or  `@lesson = student.lessons.where(student_id: student).where(instructor_id: @instructor.id).first_or_create(params)` if you want to check for extant records (depending on your data schema)

Comment: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass